# When writing to SD card, does it matter if I write zeros or ones?

Tags: sd-card, flash-memory

As I understand it, a flash cell is 'flashed' (erased) by setting all bits to one. Afterwards, the actual value is then written by setting bits to zero.

Does that mean that, if I have a file and I update certain bits from one to zero, I can use the card for longer than if I write bits from zero to one? Or is there firmware getting in the way (e.g. wear leveling) that would nullify this? Does the filesystem choice influence this?

Comment: "*As I understand it, ...*" -- Your understanding is incomplete. NAND flash has to be erased prior to writing. Erasure causes all bits to be set to ones. Then, when the sector is written, only the bits that are written with zeros are actually changed. Writing a one does not change the bit. So there is no "*write bits from zero to one*". Unless you're using raw flash, the storage drive uses an FTL that ensures that "re-writing" a (logical) sector actually uses a remapped and already-erased physical sector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean that, if I have a file and I update certain bits from
>   one to zero, I can use the card for longer than if I write bits from
>   zero to one?

No, you can't use the card for longer than if you write bits from zero to one.

---

Wear levelling is handled by the file system you choose to write in the SD card. For example, Jffs2 (most commonly used flash filesystem) will take care of wear levelling in the SD card.

At SD card side the microcontroller implements a FTL (Flash Translation Layer) that takes disk-like block accesses and translates it into meaningful NAND operations, as well as performing wear-levelling and block sparing.

Comment: "*Wear levelling is handled by the file system you choose to write in the SD card*" -- False. Your example is bogus. JFFS2 is a filesystem for raw NAND flash, and cannot be used with SD cards. Nor do SD cards use JFFS2, since they offer a block device interface, and never the JFFS2 filesystem interface.